# Total of Count in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to count the occurrences of a question number across timepoints regardless of whether they are the same within each timepoint. For example - I have split a table into weeks and number of questions within each week:

| Weeks | Number of Questions |
| --- | --- |
| First Use | 34 |
| Week 1 | 58 |
| Week 2 | 47 |
| Week 4 | 45 |
| Week 8 | 45 |

The number of questions comes from the count of question number column within a column. Week 4 and Week 8 contain the same question numbers (as week 8 was a repeat of week 4). I want to total all values in that column.

[Count table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXxvZ.png)

I've tried a new measure:

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA('Question Mapping'[Question No])
)
```

and filtered on week 8. It gives 45 but when I add week 4 to the filter the result is still 45 when I need it to be 90.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your data model (tables & relationships) then you can try:

```
  SUMX(
    'a table'[Your Weeks Column],
    COUNTA('Question Mapping'[Question No]
  )
```